# How to use boolean indexing for substring relation in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am trying to count which strings in a pandas dataframe are substrings of a given string. I don't want to use lists or loops but would like to use succinct pandas-internal syntax to accomplish this.

I just can't get the logics to work. This is what I have:

```
import pandas

given = 'abcdef'

df = pandas.DataFrame(['abc', 'cde', 'aaa'],columns=['A'])

matches = df[(df.A in given)]
```

What I want is a subframe of `df` that only contains entries satisfying the boolean condition. I can't be that hard ... but I seem to be unable to get it right.

Comment: Clearly, `df.A` is not a string ... so this is where things go wrong. But what is the pythonic and panda-esque way of expressing what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html). Example -

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x in given)]
```

Demo -

```
In [22]: df = pandas.DataFrame(['abc', 'cde', 'aaa'],columns=['A'])

In [23]: given = 'abcdef'

In [24]: df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: x in given)]
Out[24]:
     A
0  abc
1  cde
```